# SELECT query in MYSQL stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I need to run following query in my stored function with variables

```
SELECT json_unquote(json_extract(value,'$."_key"')) INTO org_rank_value FROM preferences WHERE id=_id;
```

Here _key and _id are declared variables, but _key is not replaced with value since it is in quotes. Is there any way to build and execute above query?

Comment: Could you give me some example data from the table?

Comment: I don't know if this is going to work, but you can construct `'$."_key"'` in a variable before the select using the `CONCAT` function and then use the variable in the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

Without more context about your database structure, this is how i interpreted your question.

1) you want to select a specific ID.

2) you want to change a parameter within your json-field based off of the ID.

3) you want to execute the query.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT org_rank_value FROM preferences WHERE id=_id)
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (  
    yourKey varchar(200) '$.key' -- change to whatever your variables are. 
 )  AS changeKey;
UPDATE preferences SET json_unquote(json_extract(value,'$."_key"')) INTO org_rank_value WHERE id=_id;
```

In MySQL, u can use 
[JSON_ARRAY_APPEND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html)

Comment: I need to get value of the key in a json datatype and this should set into variable in my function

Comment: @Vinay Updated the answer.

Comment: @Vinay My first query did exactly that tho. but if you **HAVE** to use your query.. try the above.

Comment: OPENJSON is not available in MySQL database

Comment: Okay, thought it was avaliable in mySql. U can use `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` instead. I'll update the answer.